# Ubuntu 20.10 RPI4 wont open jarfile

Tags: command-line, java, raspberrypi, 20.10, minecraft

So a while ago I got my rpi4 to use ubuntu with the purpose of making a Minecraft server, I downloaded the jarfile and tried to open it, it would show the following error:

```
We appear to be missing one or more essential library files. You will need to add them to your server before FML and Forge will run successfully.java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.run(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:52)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.main(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:34)
```

**I have tried from reinstalling the JDK to even having to change the default version but to no avail.** The installer unpacks 2 files, the jarfile and a folder named 'libraries', when I try to open the jarfile it does not open, and when opened in the terminal it shows the error above.
Any ideas on how to solve?

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the JDK, the error message is clear:

> We appear to be missing one or more essential library files. You will
> need to add them to your server before FML and Forge will run
> successfully.java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch

This [article](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/java-edition-support/2947305-unable-to-launch-java-lang-classnotfoundexception) suggests that your code might be corrupt and needs to be reinstalled

On the other hand you've been vague about what your are trying to achieve. If you're setting up a Forge mod loader onto your server you'll need to download the `FMLLIBS Libraries`. Unpack them and add the to the libraries folder of your server.

Last not least you didn't mention the Ubuntu version on your device.

Comment: Thanks, but where can I find these libraries?